# how to store bytes like b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x009bwR\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 to dataframe or csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I am requesting a URL and getting a return in bytes. I want to store this in a data frame and then to CSV.

```
#Get Data from the CSV 
url = "someURL" 
req = requests.get(URL)
url_content = req.content
csv_file = open('test.txt', 'wb')
print(type(url_content))
print(url_content)
csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

I tried many approaches, but couldn't find the solution. The above code is storing the output in CSV, but getting the below error. My end objective is to store this in CSV then send it to google cloud. And create a google big query table.

[image]

Output:

```
    <class 'bytes'>
 
 
 
 b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x009bwR\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00[Content_Types].xml\xb5S\xcbn\xc20\x10\xfc\x95\xc8\xd7*6\xf4PU\x15\x81C\x1f\xc7\x16\xa9\xf4\x03\\{\x93X\xf8%\xaf\xa1\xf0\xf7]\x078\x94R\x89\nq\xf2cfgfW\xf6d\xb6q\xb6ZCB\x13|\xc3\xc6|\xc4*\xf0*h\xe3\xbb\x86},^\xea{Va\x96^K\x1b<4\xcc\x076\x9bN\x16\xdb\x08XQ\xa9\xc7\x86\xf59\xc7\x07!P\xf5\xe0$\xf2\x10\xc1\x13\xd2\x86\xe4d\xa6c\xeaD\x94j);\x10\xb7\xa3\xd1\x9dP\xc1g\xf0\xb9\xceE\x83M\'O\xd0\xca\x95\xcd\xd5\xe3\xee\xbeH7L\xc6h\x8d\x92\x99R\x89\xb5\xd7G\xa2\xf5^\x90\'\xb0\x03\x07{\x13\xf1\x86\x08\xacz\xde\x90\xca\xae\x1bB\x91\x893\x1c\x8e\x0b\xcb\x99\xea\xdeh.\xc9h\xf8W\xb4\xd0\xb6F\x81\x0ej\xe5\xa8\x84CQ\xd5\xa0\xeb\x98\x88\x98\xb2\x81}\xce\xb9L\xf9U:\x12\x14D\x9e\x13\x8a\x82\xa4\xf9%\xde\x87\xb1\xa8\x90\xe0,\xc3B\xbc\xc8\xf1\xa8[\x8c\t\xa4\xc6\x1e ;\xcb\xb1\x97\t\xf4{N\xf4\x98~\x87\xd8X\xf1\x83p\xc5\x1cykOL\xa1\x04\x18\x90kN\x80V\xee\xa4\xf1\xa7\xdc\xbfBZ~\x86\xb0\xbc\x9e\x7fq\x18\xf6\x7f\xd9\x0f \x8aa\x19\x1fr\x88\xe1{O\xbf\x01PK\x07\x08z\x94\xcaq;\x01\x00\x00\x1c\x04\x00\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x009bwR\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00_rels/.rels\xad\x92\xc1j\xc30\x0c\x86_\xc5\xe8\xde8\xed`\x8cQ\xb7\x972\xe8m\x8c\xee\x014[ILb\xcb\xd8\xda\x96\xbd\xfd\xcc.[K\n\x1b\xec($}\xff\x07\xd2v?\x87I\xbdQ.\x9e\xa3\x81u\xd3\x82\xa2h\xd9\xf9\xd8\x1bx>=\xac\xee@\x15\xc1\xe8p\xe2H\x06"\xc3~\xb7}\xa2\t\xa5n\x94\xc1\xa7\xa2*"\x16\x03\x83H\xba\xd7\xba\xd8\x81\x02\x96\x86\x13\xc5\xda\xe98\x07\x94Z\xe6^\'\xb4#\xf6\xa47m{\xab\xf3O\x06\x9c3\xd5\xd1\x19\xc8G\xb7\x06u\xc2\xdc\x93\x18\x98\'\xfd\xcey|a\x1e\x9b\x8a\xad\x8d\x8fD\xbf\t\xe5\xae\xf3\x96\x0el_\x03EY\xc8\xbe\x98\x00\xbd\xec\xb2\xf9vql\x1f3\xd7ML\xe9\xbfeh\x16\x8a\x8e\xdc*\xd5\x04\xca\xe2\xa9\\3\xbaY0\xb2\x9c\xe9oJ\xd7\x8f\xa2\x03\t:\x14\xfc\xa2^\x08\xe9\xb3\x1f\xd8}\x02PK\x07\x08\xa7\x8cz\xbd\xe3\x00\x00\x00I\x02\x00\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x009bwR\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00docProps/app.xmlM\x8e\xc1\n\xc20\x10D\xef~E\xc8\xbd\xdd\xeaAD\xd2\x94\x82\x08\x9e\xecA? \xa4\xdb6\xd0lB\xb2J?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original URL (now edited out of the question) suggests that the downloaded file is in `.xlsx` format.  The `.xlsx` format is essentially one or more xml files in a zip archive ([iBug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66831280/5320906) is correct in this respect).

Therefore if you want to get the file's data in a dataframe, tell Pandas to read it as an excel file.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "someURL" 
req = requests.get(URL)
url_content = req.content

# Load into a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(url_content)

# Write to csv
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Answer (score 5):

The initial bytes `PK\x03\x04` suggest that it's PK Zip format. Try unzipping it first, either with `unzip x <filename>` or with Python builtin [`zipfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).

Comment: How can one get the file name from inside the zip file to pass to zipfile('file_name.csv')?