# Unable to read csv file data without using external packages - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, csv, file-upload, phpexcel

I'm trying to upload the CSV file and analyze the CSV data without using any package and upload it to the database in laravel 9 using [this guide](https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-9-upload-csv-file-example-without-packages). For now, I'm just trying to print the CSV data on the web using echo, I'm facing some issues.

**1)** When I am trying to print `record` using `str_getcsv`, I get the record in the following format.

```
 $records = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));
```

Error

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => b"PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00b¯Øh^\x01\x00\x00É\x04\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml ó\x04\x02(á\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 ▶"
  1 => b"ÓÑÃ×DO97*é~º╚╔©8└OÝc\x1C|nªÐ\x07õ\x04E° \x14÷\x11Ú║¾└B\x10╔└!$}çÝÓ╚Ú;{ýðÕ[â¯±ûÚ\x7F2■\x06\x00\x00  \x03\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00ÁU0#¶\ ▶"
  2 => b"Š\x12 –"
  3 => b"g·¥\x06EV\x11\x07ï[.$YµÓvà{V%ßÎç?va­┌Ø└┤ÀU┴b)öHu\x07áØå¶× Ïu0Ì\tAÁ\x1FâÀ!¨Äñw╠õ­ëòý┐ôU \t½ \få¦\x0FúaÉV¡ò\x00é¸N┤Ì\x137\x0FìÄRûË╦F║\x16)╦\x1Fñ0Ö╩æò\x13Ñg\tË4\tÐ ▶"
  4 => b"\x07«×ÃÞ\x109£'9ŸJX@î£\SÉ‰¦\x13Á5HmKý£²ª±'™\x00\x11[gôÏšI"
]
```

Is it how I'm supposed to get results with the above command and convert it to a readable format using some code.

**2)** Why is it true? `count($fields) != count($records)`. In the CSV file that I uploaded, every record has the same number of fields as the CSV file as shown below screenshot.

My code is not executing after that. So, I don't know what's gonna happened next, I've searched online. But didn't get any help. Please someone help.

**These are the functions inside the `customerController` file**

```
// IMPORTING DATA
    private $rows = [];

    public function import(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
        echo ($path);
        echo "<br>";
        $records = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));

        if (!count($records) > 0) {
            return 'Error...';
        }

        // Get field names from header column
        $fields = array_map('strtolower', $records[0]);

        // Remove the header column
        array_shift($records);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $records; $i++) {
            echo ("Feilds length : " . count($fields));
            echo "<br>";
            echo ("Records at index " . $i . " length : " . count($records[$i]));
            echo "<br>";
            if (count($fields) != count($records[$i])) {
               return 'csv_upload_invalid_data';
            }

            // Decode unwanted html entities
            $record =  array_map("html_entity_decode", $records[$i]);


            // Set the field name as key
            // $record = array_combine($fields, $record);

            // Get the clean data
            $this->rows[] = $this->clear_encoding_str($record);
            $temp = $this->clear_encoding_str($record);
        }

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            if (count($fields) != count($record)) {
                return 'csv_upload_invalid_data';
            }

            // Decode unwanted html entities
            $record =  array_map("html_entity_decode", $record);

            // Set the field name as key
            $record = array_combine($fields, $record);

            // Get the clean data
            $this->rows[] = $this->clear_encoding_str($record);
        }

        foreach ($this->rows as $data) {
            User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->with('success', 'Done');
    }

    private function clear_encoding_str($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $clean = [];
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                $clean[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($val, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
            }
            return $clean;
        }
        return mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
    }
```

**Code inside blade file**

```
<form action="{{ route('customer.import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload CSV</button>
</form>
```

This is the output I'm getting on the browser.

[image]

CSV file that I'm trying to upload

[image]

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66831280/1597430
In short words, this is not CSV.

Comment: `$records = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));` is incorrect. CSV can contain newline characters as part of the data.

Comment: @user1597430 says the unzipping file will work but I tried to edit unzip file like the following but it is still the same record in the same format. https://paste-bin.xyz/58042

Comment: @HonkderHase so what should I do?

Comment: If you had a valid CSV: use a file pointer and `fgetcsv()`